# change menu color item when active

Tags: javascript, html, css

EDIT: It is working with this code:

```
        <div id="navigation">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="/index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/about">About Me</a></li>
                <li><a href="/blog">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="/projects">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="/time">Current Time</a></li>
                <li><a href="/help">Help Me</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

And the code to make the class active:

```
        <script>
            $(function () {
                var url = window.location.pathname,
                    urlRegExp = new RegExp(url.replace(/\/$/, '') + "$");
                    $('#navigation a').each(function () {
                    if (urlRegExp.test(this.href.replace(/\/$/, ''))) {
                        $(this).addClass('active');
                    }
                });    
            });
        </script>
```

This is working now, but when i'm going to `Site/Projects/Project1` It makes nothing active. And when i go to `Site/Project`s it makes the projects tab active.

So it is working, but i also want the projects tab to stay active when i'm on `Site/Projects/Project1`

Comment: Instead of editing your question to post your answer, you can answer your own question.

Comment: But as you can see, this is not the answer yet.

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted "It is working with" to mean that you had solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, i got it with a little bit of php.
How my code looks right now:

```
$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
    //If the link is http://localhost:8080/ (Homepage), Then make "Home" Active
    if($actual_link == "http://localhost:8080/"){
        ?>
            <div id="navigation">
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li><a class="active" href="/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/about">About Me</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/blog">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/projects">Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/time">Current Time</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/help">Help Me</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    <?php
    }
    //If link is not http://localhost:8080/ Then do this.
    else{
        ?>
    <div id="navigation">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <?php
                //If the links is LIKE http://localhost:8080/about Then make it active
                //So http://localhost:8080/about/lalala will make about active!
                if (strpos($actual_link,'http://localhost:8080/about') !== false) { ?>
            <li><a class="active" href="/about">About Me</a></li>
                <?php }else{ ?>
            <li><a href="/about">About Me</a></li>
                <?php }
                //If the links is LIKE http://localhost:8080/blog Then make it active
                //So http://localhost:8080/blog/lalala will make blog active!
                if (strpos($actual_link,'http://localhost:8080/blog') !== false) { ?>
            <li><a class="active" href="/blog">Blog</a></li>
                <?php }else{ ?>
            <li><a href="/blog">Blog</a></li>
                <?php }
                //If the links is LIKE http://localhost:8080/projects Then make it active
                //So http://localhost:8080/projects/lalala will make projects active!
                if (strpos($actual_link,'http://localhost:8080/projects') !== false) { ?>
            <li><a class="active" href="/projects">Projects</a></li>
                <?php }else{ ?>
            <li><a href="/projects">Projects</a></li>
                <?php }
                //If the link is LIKE http://localhost:8080/contact Then make it active
                //So http://localhost:8080/contact/lalala will make time active!
                if (strpos($actual_link,'http://localhost:8080/contact') !== false) { ?>
            <li><a class="active" href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
                <?php }else{ ?>
            <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
                <?php }
                //If the link is LIKE http://localhost:8080/time Then make it active
                //So http://localhost:8080/time/lalala will make time active!
                if (strpos($actual_link,'http://localhost:8080/time') !== false) { ?>
            <li><a class="active" href="/time">Current Time</a></li>
                <?php }else{ ?>
            <li><a href="/time">Current Time</a></li>
                <?php }
                //If the link is LIKE http://localhost:8080/help Then make it active
                //So http://localhost:8080/help/lalala will make help active!
                if (strpos($actual_link,'http://localhost:8080/help') !== false) { ?>
            <li><a class="active" href="/help">Help Me</a></li>
                <?php }else{ ?>
            <li><a href="/help">Help Me</a></li>
                <?php } ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <?php
    }
```

And i got it working :D Thanks for the help!

Comment: I was in the middle of editing my answer when I spotted this!
Glad you got it working. Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

Array index starting from zero. But you have started the for loop with count=1. May be that cause the issue. Kindly change the following code and test it out.

```
for(i=1;i<aObj.length;i++) {
```

should be

```
 for(i=0;i<=aObj.length;i++) {
```

Comment: Right now it always selects the Home page. So when i'm on about. it higlights the home and the about page. Also the time page still does not work!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you're happy to use jQuery on your page or not.

But here's a possible solution if you are:

https://jsfiddle.net/fwLfdn8w/16/

Have set it to compare all anchors to:

```
location.pathname
```

and add the class of active if they match

Comment: When i'm on my index.php, it turns everything green. And when i go for example to About me or Clock or etc. Nothing is green.

Comment: @Mitch I'm struggling to replicate the problem. Unless they all have the same href then it should only add the class of active to the anchor that matches?

Comment: I have my index.php. then i have folders like: Time, About Me etc etc. Now, when i'm on the homepage (index.php) all the menu items turn green. example here: http://portfoliomw.besaba.com/

Comment: Try this:

`$(function(){
    var url = window.location.pathname, 
        urlRegExp = new RegExp(url.replace(/\/$/,'') + "$");
        $('#menu a').each(function(){
            if(urlRegExp.test(this.href.replace(/\/$/,''))){
                $(this).addClass('active');
            }
        });

});`

Comment: This works, but when i'm on my index.php everthing gets higlighted.

Comment: I think it's because the URL doesn't have a pathname. It's just the domain name. If it's only that one page it doesn't work on you could hardcode in the active class to the correct menu item and remove the script.

Comment: i see / understand. thank you. 1 thing though. When i go to for example: Site/Projects. The projects tab get highlighted. But when i go to: Site/Projects/Project1 , nothing gets higlighted.

Comment: Ahhh. That might need a bit of refiddling to see if it 'contains' the pathname in oppose to matching it. That extra '/project1' stops it from matching. I'm currently at work so can't help you right now. But will do so next time I log at home!